# Show JSON format from input value

Tags: angularjs

I dont understand, what the return value is back to as string, while the console.log is showing perfect formate, which required.

```
function syntaxHighlight(json) {
            json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
            return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
                var cls = 'number';
                if (/^"/.test(match)) {
                    if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                        cls = 'key';
                    } else {
                        cls = 'string';
                    }
                } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
                    cls = 'boolean';
                } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
                    cls = 'null';
                }
                return match ;
            });
        }
        var obj = { a: 1, 'b': 'foo', c: [false, 'false', null, 'null', { d: { e: 1.3e5, f: '1.3e5' } }] };
        var str = JSON.stringify(obj , undefined, 4);

        console.log(syntaxHighlight(str));
        $scope.jsonText = syntaxHighlight(str);
```

HTML

```
  <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.frmFormatJSON()">
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label>Format JSON</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="{}" ng-model="vm.formatJSON">
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="formatJSON">
                    Look
               </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Console.log**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**update**
as per @Fissio suggestion, 
its working perfect, but once I update

```
var str = JSON.stringify(vm.formatJSON, undefined, 4);
```

its again show in 1 line, also confuse why **" "** at the begning and end of the output.

Comment: Can you please add the html code that is displaying your output?

Comment: `<td ng-bind-html="jsonText"></td>`  or `<td>{{jsonText}}</td>`, i tried both. Result should be like console.log ,

Comment: So what's wrong with the output? Looks like it's just the same as the console.logged value...?

Comment: @Fissio, I mean the format, its just straight line

Comment: @faisal Oh okay, check the answer posted for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use HTML `<pre>` tag and angular's `json` filter.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    a: {
      b: [1, 2, 3],
      c: {
        nested: "json"
      }
    },
    lol: {
      5: "asd",
      asd: "5"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <pre>{{data | json:4}}</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you check the updated part in my question. might you know this.

Comment: Don't use JSON.stringify at all for this; all you need to have is the raw JSON data.

Comment: my appologies, I am learning, I didnt get how to do this, any snippet?

Comment: There's the code snippet in my answer - forget the .stringify() altogether, the JSON data itself is what you want to have as the data - so since your data seems to be in a variable `vm.formatJSON`, your html should be `<pre>{{vm.formatJson | json:4}}</pre>`

Comment: yes, might I didnt explain well, there is a input field, what ever json enter, it just show the in format.

Comment: (just for concept: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) input field to enter and show the json when click Process button.
** no need to validate**

Comment: Check https://plnkr.co/edit/8hIy11PlU77X9w0aUK5z?p=preview - basically the ng-model is a string, and in the `<pre>` tags we display a `JSON.parse()`d output with the `json` filter.

Comment: GREAT :), God bless you :)